# Trying to match luminosity of images using Pillow Module in Python

Tags: python, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I am trying to match the luminosity distribution of two folders. Each folder has 50 images, I am attempting to ensure that both folders luminosity's (saturation, brightness, contrast, hue) are the same.

What I've tried to do is:

1. Calculate luminosity measures for each image
2. Sort images on each measures
3. Pair images on each measure with a corresponding image in the other folder that matches (e.g, matching the 50th brightest image in folder A with the 50th brightest image in folder B, and then match the 50th lowest saturation image in folder A with the equivalent in folder B). Note this sorting and matching is done on each luminosity dimension separately
4. Take the midpoint between these images and use that point as the "target" that both images will be adjusted to
5. Use the Pillow enhance model and the factor ("target luminosity metric" / "current luminosity measure") to modify the images to the desired point.

Up to step 4 seems to be working properly (mid point of both folders after calculations are exactly the same, factor is mathematically correct), but when I adjust the images and then recheck the luminosity measures on the modified images the distributions don't merge and the individual images luminosity metrics don't match the midpoints. Not sure why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, is this due to a bug or is there something in the Pillow enhance module that explains why the images aren't adjusting as expected?

Listed above:

Here is some of my functions

```
def calculate_mid(df, column):
        """Calculates a list of midpoints between 2 images in the same position of a distribution and returns a 
    list of this in order for each luminosity column"""
    df_ai = df[df['ANSWER'] =="AI"]
    df_real = df[df['ANSWER'] !="AI"]
    lum_ai = df_ai.sort_values(by=[f'{column}'], ascending=True)
    lum_real = df_real.sort_values(by=[f'{column}'], ascending=True)
    mid_list = []

    d = {}
    for img in range(len(df_ai)): #loop that calculates mid
        ai = lum_ai.iloc[img][f'{column}']
        real = lum_real.iloc[img][f'{column}']
        mid = (ai + real)/2
        mid_list.append(mid)
        d[lum_ai.iloc[img][f'IMG_ID']]=  mid
        d[lum_real.iloc[img][f'IMG_ID']]=  mid
        lum_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index', columns=[f'{column}_Midpoint'])
        #print(f"AI:{ai}, Real:{real}, Mid: {mid}")
    return (mid_list, lum_df)


def image_targets(df, columns):
    """Runs through a list of luminosity columns, calculates mid and then combines them into a single df"""
    lum_df = pd.DataFrame()
    
    for col in columns:
        mid_list, lum = calculate_mid(df, col)
        lum_df = pd.concat([lum_df, lum], axis=1)  # Concatenate horizontally (column-wise)
    lum_df['IMG_ID'] = lum_df.index
    return lum_df

def adjust_image_properties(image_path, output_path, output_path_ai, output_path_real, filename,
                            brightness_factor, contrast_factor):
    # Open the image using Pillow
    img = Image.open(image_path)

    # Adjust brightness
    brightness = ImageEnhance.Brightness(img)
    img = brightness.enhance(brightness_factor)

    # Adjust contrast
    contrast = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img)
    img = contrast.enhance(contrast_factor)

    # # Convert to HSV mode to adjust saturation
    # img = img.convert("HSV")

    # # Adjust saturation
    # saturation = ImageEnhance.Color(img)
    # img = saturation.enhance(saturation_factor)

    # Convert back to RGB mode
    img = img.convert("RGB")

    # Print adjustment factors for debugging
    print(f"Filename: {filename}")
    print(f"Brightness Factor: {brightness_factor}")
    print(f"Contrast Factor: {contrast_factor}")
    #print(f"Saturation Factor: {saturation_factor}")

    # Save the adjusted image
    output_path2 = os.path.join(output_path, filename)
    img.save(output_path2)

    if "ai" in filename:
        output_path_ai = os.path.join(output_path_ai, filename)
        img.save(output_path_ai)
    else:
        output_path_real = os.path.join(output_path_real, filename)
        img.save(output_path_real)


for filename in os.listdir(og_50):
    image = os.path.join(og_50, filename)
    img_df = d50[d50['IMG_ID'] == filename]
    """Gets factors for each image"""
    factor = {}
    for col in columns:
        mid = f'{col}_Midpoint'
        factor[col] = img_df[mid] / img_df[col]
    adjust_image_properties(image, adj_50, ai50_folder, real50_folder, filename,
                            brightness_factor=factor["img_brightness"], 
                            contrast_factor=factor["img_contrast"])`
```

Comment: If all steps up to 4) work correctly, that means all the `pandas`, sorting, `os.pathjoin()` code is irrelevant to your answer, so your [mcve] should provide sample input images and corresponding current and expected output images along with the enhancement code and the parameters you have calculated. Otherwise you are narrowing the field of folk who might answer to those who know `pandas` and statistics and image processing and PIL.

Comment: I think I figure it out, issue is there are some pixels that are at or near 255 values (or 0 values) and when i upscale or downscale their luminosity measure it won't increase beyond (below) these marks since they're the max/min value a pixel can take.